# How to start Unity 3D

Tags: 11.10

The unity_support_test showed "yes" in every item, but when signing in I can only choose between Ubuntu and Ubuntu 2D (card is GeForce 6600 GT). What can I do to start the 3D-mode?
Hubert

Answer (score 4):

The names are slightly confusing but Ubuntu is Unity 3D and Ubuntu 2D is Unity 2D.

When you are logged into Ubuntu (Unity 3D) you can confirm compiz is running with the command

```
ps -e | grep compiz
```